# How to find paths from root to node (python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree

I'm trying to find all the paths of a tree from ROOT to NODE of a certain VALUE.

The first solution I've tried is to use recursion that stops when the node's value == value:

```
def list_paths_to_value(t, value):
    list_ = []

    for b in t.branches:
        list_ += [[t.label] + path for path in list_paths_to_value(b, value)]

    if t.label == value:
        return [[t.label]]
    return list_

one_branch_two_depth = Tree(1, [Tree(2, [Tree(2)])])

list_paths_to_value(one_branch_two_depth, 2)

Output:
[[1,2]]
```

The output should be [[1,2], [1,2,2]] but my output is not able to return the [1,2,2] path.

My other solution was to force the recursive function to only stop at the leaf of the tree:

```
def list_paths_to_value(t, value):
    list_ = []

    for b in t.branches:
        list_ += [[t.label] + path for path in list_paths_to_value(b, value)]

    if t.label == value and t.is_leaf():
        return [[t.label]]

    return list_

one_branch_two_depth = Tree(1, [Tree(2, [Tree(2)])])

list_paths_to_value(one_branch_two_depth, 2)

Output:
[[1,2,2]]
```

This on the other hand, did not return the [1,2] value.

Guidance on how to return the expected output would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Appending also the code for the Tree Class:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, label, branches=[]):
        for b in branches:
            assert isinstance(b, Tree)
        self.label = label
        self.branches = list(branches)

    def is_leaf(self):
        return not self.branches
```